# MLflow - How can I run python code using a REST API

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, mlflow

I'am a newbie on MachineLearning. Just a simple question, how can I run python code using REST API?
Here is the documentation
https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html
But there are no examples for REST API.
I just created an experiment, but I cant create python run?
Any examples like this? "This is create just a experiment"
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/2.0/preview/mlflow/experiments/create -d '{"name":"TEST"}'